# Pell's equation - Precision error or math error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, decimal

I'm doing project Eular's number 66, which is about pell's equation.

I've almost solved it, but i'm not getting the correct answer only an answer really close to the correct one.

I'm not sure if this is a precision error or a math error. I'm solving it by using the continued fractions method (following [this](http://www.had2know.com/academics/pell-equation-calculator.html) (at the bottom of the page))

A number like 61 should output 335159612 / 42912791 (7.81024967591 in decimal) but instead i get 29718 / 3805 (7.81024967148488830486202365... (continues)) As you can see they are really close but still not quite.

The equation for 61 should look something like this `7 + 1 / (1 + 1 / (4 + 1 / (3 + 1 / (1 + 1 / (2 + 1 / (2 + 1 / (1 + 1 / (3 + 1 / (4 + 1 / 1)))))))))` and i've tried inputting that into various calculators and gotten the same answer as my code, which leads me to believe it's a math error, but where?

Here's my code, sorry if it's a mess:

```
# Equation: x^2 * d*Y^2 = 1 where d is any non-square number
import math
from fractions import Fraction
from decimal import getcontext, Decimal

getcontext().prec = 500


def find_fractions(n):
    d = Decimal(n).sqrt()

    safeint = 0
    safe = True #  These two 'safe' are to avoid the IndexError: list index out of range error

    a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"] #  a b c d are also to avoid the list error

    while a[1:int(len(a) / 2)] != a[int(len(a) / 2) + 1:]: #  while the first half (minus the first term) is not the same as the second half (aka find where it repeats)
        a.append(math.floor(d)) # Adds the numbers for the continued fraction (fx 1 / (3 + 1/2 here 2 and 3 are the numbers) 
        d = Decimal(1 / (d - math.floor(d))) #  gets the next number for the continued fraction
        safeint += 1

        if safeint > 4 and safe: #  still to avoid list error
            del a[0]
            del a[0]
            del a[0]
            del a[0]
            safe = False

        print("Fractions: ", a)

    for e in range(0, int(len(a) / 2)): # Second half of the list is useless so this removes the repeats and the last term
        del a[-1]

    print("Useful fractions: ", a)

    g = a[0] #  The first integer (it's special because it doesn't get divided by 1 
    h = Decimal(1 / a[-1]) # last term in list divided by one

    del a[0] # Delete these two because they have already been used
    del a[-1]

    for o in range(1, len(a) + 1): # goes through the list we made with the while loop
        t = Decimal(a[-o] + h)
        h = Decimal(1 / t) 
    # Basically the for-loop does this https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/math/1/1/d/11dc14afeeb64dad18b916638aa287d7.png

    g += h # adds the one that doesn't get devided

    print("x and y =", str(Fraction(g).limit_denominator()))  # Fraction
    # Using the fraction module to make it a fraction (numerator = X and denumerator = Y)
    print(g)  # Decimal

find_fractions(61)
```

Edit: Added comments to the code

Comment: I don't understand your approach. It looks nothing like solution given at 
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellEquation.html
Could you give the reference?

Comment: Basicly i'm following this: http://www.had2know.com/academics/pell-equation-calculator.html (the method at the bottom of the page) 
The while loop find all the fractions of any non-square number (until it repeats), and then a for-loop adds them together like this: http://archives.math.utk.edu/articles/atuyl/images/img1.gif (excluding the last term).

Note that it works for a few numbers (fx 23)

Comment: @Sorrells Unrelated to your particular question. Few words though (from my experience solving Euler problems)... If your solution is based on floating point numbers and you're having precission issues you're doing it wrong ;-)

Comment: You probably should not apply `math` module methods to `Decimal` objects, as that certainly will reduce the precision in between.

Comment: @BPL You're probably right about that :P. I looked at a few other methods but this one seemed the most straight forward by a long shot.

Comment: @LutzL I only used math to get the floor of a number, i tried changing it from 'math.floor(value)' to 'int(value)' but that didn't change anything :/

Comment: can you update the code with comments? To me it looks like you saw the example in the link and harcoded the value 4. 
Take a look at the algorithm on the wolfram page. it looks much more sophisticated than your approach (and is provably correct)

Comment: @famagusta I added some comments, i hope it helps :)

Comment: The solution is [here](https://projecteuler.chat/viewtopic.php?t=1572)